# When racket will check the struct's type in a function?

Tags: lisp, racket

This program:

```
(struct pt (x y))

(define (distance p1 p2)
(sqrt (+ (sqr (- (pt-x p2) (pt-x p1)))
       (sqr (- (pt-y p2) (pt-y p1))))))

(distance (pt 0 0) (pt 3.1415 2.7172))
```

Works fine. If add a line:

```
(struct pt2 (x y))
```

Then

```
(distance (pt 0 0) (pt2 3.1415 2.7172))
```

Got error

```
pt-x: contract violation
expected: pt?
given: #<pt2>
```

I think because the function distance use "pt-x" and "pt-y" to check the struct's type. In other static typed languages, the type declare and type checking will occur in the header of function, like this:

```
(define (distance p1:pt p2:pt)
```

So as racket,if there is...maybe 100 lines code after "(define (distance p1 p2)",and will take 1 minute,then the line " (sqrt (+ (sqr (- (pt-x p2) (pt-x p1)))",found a type error,so it will waste 1 minute?

Thanks!

Comment: so if I use typed racket,can I do the static type checker at the first line of a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "waste 1 minute".

- In a sense that after `distance` is invoked, it might take 1 minute for `(pt-x p2)` to be executed?
- Or in a sense that the whole program might take 1 minute for `(pt-x p2)` to be executed?

---

If you mean the first one, you can add a contract to `distance`. E.g.,

```
#lang racket

(struct pt (x y))

(define/contract (distance p1 p2) (-> pt? pt? number?)
  (sqrt (+ (sqr (- (pt-x p2) (pt-x p1)))
           (sqr (- (pt-y p2) (pt-y p1))))))

(distance (pt 0 0) (pt 3.1415 2.7172))
```

Every time that `distance` is called, it will check that `p1` and `p2` satisfy `pt?`, and if the check fails, it will error right away. Note that this happens at run-time and only when `distance` is called. The program might run for long time without any problem and after that executes `(distance (pt2 0 0) (pt2 3.1415 2.7172))`, and only then will the error occur.

---

If you mean the second one, then you don't want the program to be run at all in order to discover the mistake. That is, you want the mistake to be discovered statically. You would need to use Typed Racket or something like that. This would be similar to languages with static type checking.

```
#lang typed/racket

(struct pt ([x : Number] [y : Number]))

(: distance : pt pt -> Number)
(define (distance p1 p2) 
  (sqrt (+ (sqr (- (pt-x p2) (pt-x p1)))
           (sqr (- (pt-y p2) (pt-y p1))))))

(distance (pt 0 0) (pt 3.1415 2.7172))
```